# КрОшит или крошИт

Tags: поэзия, орфоэпия

У А. Вознесенского есть замечательное стихотворение "Елена Сергеевна", а в нём строки:

> Елена Сергеевна ведёт урок.
> (Ленка, вспыхнув, крошит мелок.)

Где ставить ударение в слове "крошит"? Словарь на Грамоте даёт два варианта, а по ритму я понять не могу... Склоняюсь к И, но не уверена. Помогите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Резниченко (2010 год) нормативными являются обе формы: крошИт и крОшит.

Оба варианта ударения встречаются и у классиков:

Да, для нас это грязь на калошах, Да, для нас это хруст на зубах. И мы мелем, и месим, и крОшим Тот ни в чем не замешанный прах (А. Ахматова).

Ох, как крошИтся наш табак, Щелкунчик, дружок, дурак!А мог бы жизнь просвистать скворцом,
Заесть ореховым пирогом...Да, видно, нельзя никак (О. Мандельштам).

В приведенном примере, скорее, используется форма крошИт, что соответствует ритму стиха, с учетом словораздела (цезуры): ведет урок - крошИт мелок.